# VBA Word locate and replace date in text document

Tags: vba, date, ms-word

I'm looking for a way to locate all dates within a word document. The whole document is just text and the dates won't be in a consitant format. I mostly use excel and confused about how to start this in word.

Once I can find a date I will be checking if it's greater than a default date and changing it to today which won't be a problem.

Though currently I don't know how to search word for all text that could be a date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to write some code and show it to us. Your question is too broad and general to be answered as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You might at least have given us some indication of the possible date formats. The following *wildcard* Find expression:

```
[0-9]{1,2}[ ^s-/][0-9]{1,2}[ ^s-/][0-9]{2,4}
```

will find dates that are in any of the following formats-

```
D/M/YY
D/MM/YY
DD/M/YY
DD/MM/YY
D/M/YYYY
D/MM/YYYY
DD/M/YYYY
DD/MM/YYYY

D-M-YY
D-MM-YY
DD-M-YY
DD-MM-YY
D-M-YYYY
D-MM-YYYY
DD-M-YYYY
DD-MM-YYYY

D M YY
D MM YY
DD M YY
DD MM YY
D M YYYY
D MM YYYY
DD M YYYY
DD MM YYYY

M/D/YY
M/DD/YY
MM/D/YY
MM/DD/YY
M/D/YYYY
M/DD/YYYY
MM/D/YYYY
MM/DD/YYYY

M-D-YY
M-DD-YY
MM-D-YY
MM-DD-YY
M-D-YYYY
M-DD-YYYY
MM-D-YYYY
MM-DD-YYYY

M D YY
M DD YY
MM D YY
MM DD YY
M D YYYY
M DD YYYY
MM D YYYY
MM DD YYYY
```